How to compile dart programs without Error: AOT compilation failed
When I run "dart compile exe D:\projects\dt\bin\dt.dart"
it shows:
Error: AOT compilation failed
PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = 'd:\projects\dt\bin\dt.exe' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)
It to compile to a dart exe

Are you sure that that path is correct?  Does your user have permission to read that file?  When you run type D:\projects\dt\bin\dt.dart from the same command prompt window, are you able to see the Dart source code you expect?
